# Call a Method in a Collection

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I've got a collection of custom objects with a method, Update(), in each of them. I need a way to iterate over the collection and call that method. This is easy to do in C# with a List, but I'm not sure how to do it in ActionScript. Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some experimentation, I found that you can type the iteration variable in the look to the object that the list is composed of, and it opens up all the methods and properties in that object:

```
for each(var ship:Ship in ships)
{
    ship.Update();
}
```

Not too sure if this is GOOD to do or not, but it works...

Comment: This is the correct approach for iterating over a collection (Array, Vector) of objects of a fixed type.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at `Array.foreach()`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#forEach%28%29